# Qt installer framework and Visual Studio integration

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qt-installer

How to integrate the [Qt installer framework](http://qt-project.org/downloads) into Visual Studio (2012)?

I want to get an installer for the build results and execute the packaging right out of Visual Studio.

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify: I'm asking for the QT INSTALLER FRAMEWORK (1.4.0) and not for the Qt framework itself.

Comment: You can use Qt visual studio addin: http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/07/03/visual-studio-add-in-1-2-2-released/

Comment: @Hariprasad No, I don't think so. I asked for QT INSTALLER FRAMEWORK and the plugin is used for integration of Qt and not the installer framework.

Comment: I guess you should build and include the libraries manually: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtifw-master/ifw-getting-started.html